# Installing Python devel on centos

Tags: python, linux, oracle, centos, cx-oracle

```
bash-4.1# yum install python-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, rhnplugin
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * rpmforge: mirror.smartmedia.net.id
 * webtatic-el5: uk.repo.webtatic.com
http://192.168.210.26/centos/6/updates/i386/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package python-devel.x86_64 0:2.6.6-36.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python(x86-64) = 2.6.6-36.el6 for package: python-devel-2.6.6-36.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: python-devel-2.6.6-36.el6.x86_64 (centos64-x86_64)
           Requires: python(x86-64) = 2.6.6-36.el6
           Installed: python-2.6.6-37.el6_4.x86_64 (@centos64-updates-x86_64)
               python(x86-64) = 2.6.6-37.el6_4
           Available: python-2.6.6-36.el6.x86_64 (centos64-x86_64)
               python(x86-64) = 2.6.6-36.el6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Can somebody help me with above error , I am getting.
Just to let everybody know I am trying to install cx_Oracle on my CentOS system (CentOS release 6.4) and I got this error:-
 error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
So, I searched and found out to install python-devel and to do that I am getting the above error.

Answer (score 2):

You have a newer version of python installed than the corresponding source package you're trying to install.

You have python 2.6.6-37 installed but the latest available source package from your repos (that you can successfully connect to) is 2.6.6-36.

But it looks like the python you have installed came from your "updates" repo,
`http://192.168.210.26/centos/6/updates/i386/repodata/repomd.xml` which isn't working at t he moment.

If that repo also had the corresponding python-devel-2.6.6-37 package, and it worked, (didn't throw a PYCURL error) you'd be fine, yum would find that and use it.

So your first step should be fixing your LAN repo / mirror.

Comment: How do I fix my LAN repo/mirror ?